# express-validator with get service

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I want to validate my parameters in get service.

my url is like /tableref?param1&param2

my code is like this

```
app.get('/tableref\?:event&:queryObject', [
check('event').isLength({ min: 5, max:15 }),
check('queryObject').isLength({ max: 5, max:35 })
] , function(req, res) {...})
```

But I have a 404 error.

I want to use express-validator to check my params.
Before, my code was

```
 app.get('/tableref', function(req, res) {...})
```

how can I check my params with get query ? Tks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the same way you would implement it case of `post` or `put` requests.
You should just import `query` validator

```
const { query, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');


app.get("/tableref", 
    [
        query('event').isLength({ min: 5, max:15 }),
        query('queryObject').isLength({ min: 5, max:35 })
    ],
    (req, res, next) => {
        // Check validation.
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }
        return res.status(200).json({message:'valid query params'});

});
```

You url should be like this `/tableref?event=example&queryObject=anotherexample`
**Please note that using above code, your query marameter is required. If you omit one, you will get an error.
 
In case you want any of your parameter to be optional you have to add the `optional` method**

```
query('queryObject')
.optional({checkFalsy: true}).isLength({ min: 5, max:35 })
```

This way, `/tableref?event=example` request is pretty valid.

Comment: thanks for your response, but that means that I have to change the way the url is called on client side. There is no other solution ?

Comment: can you give me an example of request url?

Comment: like this /tableref?TEST1&Table_test

Comment: If i understand well, TEST1 and Table_test are going to be dynamic values. So you can use them as values instead of keys. Example `/tableref?event=TEST1&queryObject=Table_test`